# how fast are JMockit unit tests (at scales of thousands of tests)?

Tags: powermock, jmockit

Would equivalent unit tests in JMockit give a significant speed up compared to PowerMock?

Background:
I have to get unit test coverage up on a large legacy code base.
We currently have PowerMock unit tests (300+) that take over 15 minutes to run.
PowerMock has been used so far due to lots of static methods calling static methods, ad infinitum.

Expanding further we estimate the need for about 1000+ Unit test classes and want a sub 10 Minute build.

We are simultaneously breaking the dependencies and unit testing with Mockito which tends to be 4x faster than the equivalent PowerMock test, but this practice is much harder, slower and perceived as risk owing to the change to production code.

Many thanks,
Alex.

Comment: 1000 more or 1000 total?

Comment: Further, I'm not sure it's *risky* to change testing frameworks in prod code: it's just painful.

Comment: I'm underplaying the scale of this problem, thousands more is more like it, but that is also going to need splitting up... all to come.

changing test code is not perceived as risky, changing prod code is.
Prod code changes mandates lots of manual regression testing.

Comment: The only way to know would be to measure it, rewriting the tests (at least some of them) that use PowerMock to use JMockit instead.

Comment: That would be the perfect answer.
I'm happy with just anecdotal, i.e. someone with Jmockit tests: how many + how long do they take + on machine of capability x.

Comment: JMockit's own test suite, containing nearly 1400 JUnit tests (all of them using the mocking APIs), runs in about 15 seconds, on a typical developer workstation.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised by the numbers you get: 300+ powerMock tests (or test classes ?) that take over 15 minutes ? That's a lot. As a comparison, we have ~100 test classes using powermock, with ~5 @Test in each of these test classes (i.e. ~500 tests) spread over ~50 Maven (root) reactors for a total of 450+ modules. All (12500+) UT tests (including the PowerMock ones) are executed in 5:07 minutes. The tests that take a lot of time are ITs not UTs. Are you sure your tests run in 15 minutes or is it the build that runs during 15 minutes ? Regards.

Comment: Hi Kraal, thats a very different experience you have there, thanks for sharing. to clarify, it is as you suggest 1000+ test classes.